# How can you check if an object is one of an array of types?

Tags: swift, filter, contains

Given the following array:

```
let ignoredViewControllerTypes:[UIViewController.Type] = [
    ViewControllerB.self,
    ViewControllerC.self
]

let allViewControllers = [
    viewControllerAInstance,
    viewControllerBInstance,
    viewControllerCInstance,
    viewControllerDInstance
]
```

What is the syntax to filter `allViewControllers` so that it excludes those types in `ignoredViewControllerTypes`?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
let filteredControllers = allViewControllers.filter{ !ignoredViewControllerTypes.contains($0.self) }
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let filteredControllers = allViewControllers.filter { viewController in
    !ignoredViewControllerTypes.contains(where: { type(of: viewController) == $0 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down in subtasks:

1. you want to check if a controller should be allowed or not

   ```
   func isAllowed(_ controller: UIViewController) -> Bool {
       return !ignoredViewControllerTypes.contains { controller.isKind(of:  $0) }
   }
   ```
2. you want to filter an array of controllers:

   ```
   let filteredControllers = allViewControllers.filter(isAllowed)
   ```

Note that `isAllowed` also filters subclasses of the ignored controllers, if you want exact type match then you should use @dan's answer.

---

As a bonus, and because I like functional programming, you can make `isAllowed` a pure and flexible function by converting it to a high-order function:

```
func doesntBelong(to prohibitedClasses: [AnyClass]) -> (AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return { obj in
        prohibitedClasses.contains { obj.isKind(of: $0) }
    }
}
```

, which can be used like this:

```
let filteredControllers = allViewControllers.filter(doesntBelong(to: ignoredViewControllerTypes))
```

Comment: This is really effing cool (i.e. your functional part.)  Not familiar with that double-arrow syntax tho. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Wait! I got it!  It's returning a closure of '(AnyObject) -> Bool'  Just clicked.

Comment: @MarqueIV yes, you got it right, that syntax says that `doesntBelong(to:)` returns a function that takes an object as argument and returns a `Bool`. You can think of it as a "function factory".